# Getting Data from inside a node in XMl with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So im not sure what or how to really describe what i need but hopefully someone will understand.

single element of the total xml file looks like this:

```
for ( $counter = 1; $counter load($file_xml); //make sure path is correct
  $note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Event");

  // Loop through XML feed
  $i = 0;
  foreach( $note as $value )
  {
    $event_id       = $value->getAttribute('ID');
    # venue id
    $VenueID        = $value->getElementsByTagName("Venue");
    $venue_id       = $VenueID->item(0)->getAttribute("ID");
  }
}
```

arrgggg its not really copying he code exactly. geez.

the top is the iteration of the for loop. inside the foreach statement I have the insert statement; which is where I am trying to insert the image URL

```
<Event ID="IDIDIDIDID">
   <EventName>EVENT NAME</EventName>
   <Artist>
      <ArtistName>ARTIST NAME</ArtistName>
   </Artist>

   <Venue ID="IDIDIDID">
    <VenueName>VENUE NAME</VenueName>
       <Image>
           <Url>IMAGE_URL</Url>
           <Width>205</Width>
           <Height>115</Height>
        </Image>
      </Venue>
 </Event>
```

I am able to get the rest of the imageofmation I need, except for the image URL. i have tried to break it up as an array and get the first value but that didnt work. I saw another post here and tried to use preg_match but that didnt work. does anyone know how i could:

get the URL of the image inside the individual "Event" row?

this is the beginning of what I have:

```
$Image          = $value->getElementsByTagName("Image");
$venue_img_2    = $Image->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

this will return IMAGE_URL 205 115

Note: the "space" between the IMAGE_URL and 205 and 115 doesn't seem to actually be a "space"

thanks in advance.

Comment: note that the item(1) is because artist also has an <image> piece in it. I just removed it for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Event nodes have one parent (ie `<Events><Event>...</Event><Event>...</Event></Events>`):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file_xml);

foreach($xml->Event as $event) {
    $idAttr = 'ID';

    $event_id = (string) $event->attributes()->$idAttr;
    $venue_id = (string) $event->Venue->attributes()->$idAttr;

    $venue_img_2 = (string) $event->Venue->Image->Url;
}
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if the $file_xml is returns from a URL (api) as XML?  and the structure is: <results><Details><TotalResults>14214</TotalResults><TotalPages>143</TotalPages><CurrentPage>1</CurrentPage><ResultsPerPage>100</ResultsPerPage></Details><Event>ALL the info</Event></results>

Comment: I am also using this currently: $objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$objDOM->load($file_xml);
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Details");

Comment: @user450784: It should work as is with the xml being structured like that.

Comment: I just tried your code exactly with the $file_xml being the api url for the data that gets returned as xml, but i get some errors. 1. Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found ---- 2. Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: http://api.perfb.com/api/api.php?api_key=API_KEY&act in ---- 3. Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in ---- 4. Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ---- 5. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @user450784: If you want to load the xml directly from a url its needs to be `simplexml_load_file()` instead. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That worked like a champ!!!! cOle2 you rock. thanks so much for taking the time to go through this for me. I really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("books.xml") 
   or die("Error: Cannot create object");

  foreach($xml->children() as $books){
foreach($books->children() as $book => $data){
  echo $data->id;
  echo $data->title;
  echo $data->author;
  echo "<br />";
}
```

}